# How does $P(x_{0}) \land \forall y \forall z ((P(y) \land P(z) \rightarrow y=z) \land P(y)$ imply $y=x_{0}$

Tags: solution-verification, proof-writing

Ive been looking at this for a while and have absolutely no clue how these assumptions imply that $y=x_{0}$

Comment: Is the last $p(y)$ meant to be $P(y)$?

Comment: Yea my badddddd

Comment: You have $P(x_0) \land P(y)$ from which we conclude what?

Comment: @copper.hat we know both $P(y) \land P(x_{0})$, so the goal $y = x_{0}$ follows from the
second assumption, the one with binded variables. But i dont see how

Comment: Well, using $y$ as both a bound and unbound variable is not a great idea. But since $P(x_0)$ you can choose $z=x_0$ and $y=y$ in the second clause.

Answer (score 1):

Stuff you have:

1. $P(x_0)$
2. $P(y)$
3. $\forall y,z.\ P(y)\land P(z) \rightarrow y=z$

The third one is for *all* $y$ and $z$, so in particular for the $y$ from before and for $x_0$ respectively. This gives:
$$P(y)\land P(x_0) \rightarrow y=x_0$$
As you have both $P(y)$ and $P(x_0)$, you get $y=x_0$, as you desired.

Comment: I see where im confused since i forgot that z is arbitrary which can stand for anything in this case its useful to let $z=x_{0}$ since we know that $x_{0}$ makes P true. Thanks